# Importing CSV with commas in data field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv, import, delimiter

I am importing several large CSV files.  In the process, I discovered two important pieces of information:

1. Certain data fields contain common delimiters (commas, pipes, and tabs);
2. and I found the CSV is actually several CSVs merged together by a row without data.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this question has come up many times with several different answers, and few of the answers are limited to SQL query only, so I am writing the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE #table1
 (
  data varchar(max)
 )

 BULK
 INSERT table1
 FROM 'C:\Import\file.csv'
 WITH
 (
      FIRSTROW = 1,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = 'somethingthatdoesntexist',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
 ) 
 GO

 ALTER TABLE table1 ADD id numeric NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)

 ALTER TABLE report_table ADD CONSTRAINT
      pk_id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
      (
           id
      ) WITH (
           statistics_norecompute = off,
           ignore_dup_key = off,
           allow_row_locks = on,
           allow_page_locks = on
 )
 ON [PRIMARY]
```

From there, you can use an appropriate ideology to construct where your headers are.  The first row (or first X rows) should be headers, and then the first row(s) after an empty row.  Then check for an existing table that matches or create a new table, and import that data until the next empty row.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

```
 -- Create Processed(FALSE).  Set to TRUE when properly imported.
 ALTER TABLE table1 ADD processed bit NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT c_is_processed_default_no DEFAULT FALSE

 -- Create Flagged(FALSE).  Set to TRUE when manual review required.
 --     Final step: set Flag = 1 where processed = 0; SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE flag = 1
 ALTER TABLE table1 ADD flag bit NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT c_manual_review_default_no DEFAULT FALSE
```

Fair warning, the CSV I am importing is quite large, so I'm having to work through memory errors.  Currently, I am working around this by executing each step in a separate batch.